# gsutil ch command won't let me add a user

Tags: google-cloud-storage

From reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-examples), I feel I have correct syntax but I can't add a user to have write access to my bucket. Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my setup?

```
$ gsutil acl ch -u [email address of person I want to give access]@gmail.com:WRITE 
gs://[bucket name]

CommandException: Received bad request from server: BadRequestException:
400 Invalid Value
```

Comment: Hi - what version of gsutil are you running? I just tried this command on gsutil 4.3 and it worked.

Comment: gsutil 4.3 as well: `$ gsutil version
gsutil version 4.3`

Comment: Can you please send the following output to gs-team@google.com, removing the Authorization headers before sending: gsutil -D acl ch -u [email address of person I want to give access]@gmail.com:WRITE 
gs://[bucket name]

Comment: I'm getting this same error and I just sent debug info to the gs-team address.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is fine, thus your email address is incorrect. Can you try it with another email address?